# instagram feed plugin error in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

when I am using the plugin on the home page this error is coming
We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.
I have debugged my code I think there is an error in these two lines

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $userId . '/media/recent/?access_token=' . $accessToken.'&count='.$imageNumber;

    $args = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 2500,)));
```

any help will be appricated

Comment: Which mode is enabled `production` or `developer`?

Comment: developer mode is enbaled

Comment: I think you have to double check. because if you are in `developer`  mode then error is no showing like as you mentioned in your question.
it will showing like this.
Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory \C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/m/b. Access forbidden.

Comment: i have own the developer mode from advanced setting but error is coming same

Comment: Run command `php bin/magento d:mode:set developer` and check again

Comment: Error filtering template: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2247767760/media/recent/?access_token=2247767760.ab78812.e2ce34b296e146c0976c2b4973567fc6&count=6): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /var/www/html/magento230/app/code/Solwin/Instagram/view/frontend/templates/widget/instagram.phtml on line 39 thos error is coming

Comment: In the error clearly mentioned there is a problem with in HTTP request. check and debug.

Comment: how to check http request

Comment: instagram old API is not working any more, so if anyone want to implement, he has to take a look at Facebook graph API
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-instagram-integration-pro.html